# No connecting lines are getting displayed

Tags: javascript, graph

I am using a connector framework called `js-graph-it` to connect elements on my web page. When I am running an html file to as a demonstration of working of this project it works fine but when I am including this into the project, connecting lines are missing.

Here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js-graph-it.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js-graph-it.css">

       <style>
      .canvas {
        font-family: tahoma;
      }
      .block {
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid #7DAB76;
        background-color: #BAFFB0;
        padding: 3px;
      }
      /*.connector {
        background-color: #FF9900;
      }*/
      .source-label, .middle-label, .destination-label {
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="initPageObjects();">


        <div class="canvas"
      style="width: 1350px; height: 1250px;">

       <h1 class="block" id="h1_block"
        style="left: 100px; top:10px;">
          h1 block
      </h1>

      <h2 class="block" id="h2_block"
        style="left: 800px; top: 100px;">
        h2 block
      </h2>

      <h3 class="block" id="h3_block"
        style="left: 100px; top: 180px;">
        h3 block
      </h3>

      <h2 class="block" id="h4_block"
        style="left: 100px; top: 480px;">
        h2_new block
      </h2>

  <!--   <div class="connector h1_block h2_block"></div>

        <img src="arrow.gif" class="connector-start">
        <img src="arrow.gif" class="connector-end">

        <label class="source-label">start</label>
        <label class="middle-label">middle</label>
        <label class="destination-label">end</label>

    </div> -->

    <div class="connector h1_block h2_block">
        <!-- <img class="connector-end" src="arrow.gif"> -->
    </div>

    <div class="connector h2_block h3_block">
        <!-- <img class="connector-end" src="arrow.gif"> -->
    </div>

    <div class="connector h2_block h4_block">
        <!-- <img class="connector-end" src="arrow.gif"> -->
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

and [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/alok15ee/j6nhc9y1/1/)

I am also attaching the screenshot as a proof that it is working as a standalone file.
[image: js-chart-it implemenattaion]

Comment: I really don't understand the reason for marking it as unclear or not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onDomready` to `No wrap - in <head>` in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j6nhc9y1/3/

Basically, with those “wrapped” options the `initPageObjects` function won’t be on the top level where it needs to be in order to be called from an HTML inline event handler.

---

A better alternative would be to create dynamic event handlers within the script, e.g.:

```
window.addEventListener('load',initPageObjects);
```

Comment: Thanks it's working but how do I change that inside my code do we have any option for that.

Comment: Basically, you have to put the JavaScript that is in the “Script” panel in your JSFiddle directly inside the `<head>` with no `domready` (`DOMContentLoaded`) or `load` event listeners around it. I’m not sure what you mean by “including that into the project”. You need to be more specific about it, to get more detailed help.

Comment: Sure I am using this framework inside one of an Atlassian Plugin I am developing. So I added the js-graph-it.js as one of the resource and I was calling it using <body onload="initPageObjects();">